# MSI GE Raider GE75 Ubuntu 20.04 no Speaker sound

Tags: sound, realtek, speakers, msi

I have an MSI GE75 with intel chip, realtek speakers. Tried all the fixes I can read on forum, but no sound from speakers.  Audio jack has sound.  Bluetooth sees my Beats earbuds, but will not connect and produce sound, just says "not set up".  I have deleted and reinstalled ubuntu, also updated the hardware (via windows updates etc.) but these two issues persist regardless of attempted fix. In PAVU Controller window, the Built in analog stereo speakers show up, and the sound bar moves back and forth as if playing sound when I'm running a youtube, but no output from speakers.

Comment: I'm using 'Mint" and had exactly same problem, tried days to fix. Found this post and 100% worked I'm so happy! should work for you too.. > https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?p=1906032&sid=e39b40760b16fa549b2c87eef34e6fe3#p1906032 <

Comment: Did you solve this? I am having now the same problem. I got No sound through speakers at present

Answer (score 0):

On the title you said that your OS is Ubuntu 20.04 but you also say *via windows updates etc*, what is your OS?
If you have no sound on ubuntu (or have low volume) type `alsamixer` and tweak that settings.